# Semgrep rule for a try/catch block

Tags: java, database, security, static-analysis, semgrep

I recently tried to create a Semgrep rule for Java code which detects if for a database connection happening in a try/catch block a proper rollback is done.

So what it needs to do is:

- A `Connection` object is created using `getConnection(...)` either before the try or in the `try(...)` initializer statement
- A catch block contains a call to `connection.rollback()`

How would I write such a rule in semgrep which matches a pattern before the try and in the catch block?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should work for you:

```
rules:
  - id: detect-connection-rollback
    patterns:
    - pattern:
        try{$V = getConnection(...);...}  
        catch(Exception e){... $V.rollback(...);...}
    message: Match found
    languages:
      - java
    severity: WARNING
```